# How does the predict() function used with GAMs work with generating values from original data?

Tags: r, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Hi I'm wondering if I may gain some insight on how the predict() and predict.gam() function work.

Below I have my GAM model and the name of my original dataframe I am using.

```
chamber_data_gam <-read.csv("./data_chamber_Gam.csv")
```

This dataframe has observed values for my response variable CH4.

```
c_model<-bam(CH4~ s(waterpore) + s(SoilT) + s(Size) +  s(veg) + Cover_Type +GS+ s(wetland_ID,bs="re")+ ,family=gaussian(link = "identity"),data=chamber_data_gam,select=TRUE)
```

What I am wondering is: shouldn't the predict() function produce predicted values that are **identical** to the observed CH4 values in "chamber_data_gam" if I input the original dataframe? Below is how I formatted my predict() function.

```
predicted_values_gam <-predict(c_model, 
    newdata = chamber_data_gam, type = 'response', se=TRUE)
```

When I ran my code it ran successfully but produced values that were up significant off from original values for CH4 in my dataset.

Comment: What do you think `predict` is doing? _Should_ it be returning the observed values? Hint: consider this linear model - what is `predict` doing? `x<-1:20;y<-rnorm(20)+0.3*x;mdl <- lm(y ~ x); plot(x, y); lines(x, predict(mdl), col = "red") `

Answer (score 2):

If your model was a perfect predictor of the training data it would be overfitted, and unlikely to generalise well to new data not used to train the model.

I can see a potential problem with your model. CH4 concentration or similar can't be negative and it's debatable whether you could ever measure a 0. Regardless of the 0 bit, your data will typically show a dependence between the mean and the variance of the observations (because at 0 concentration there would be 0 variance). In other words, as the mean CH4 value increase, the variance about that will will also increase. This would typically violate the assumptions of the Gaussian distribution which you have assumed as the conditional distribution of the observations. Instead, one might use the `family = Gamma(link = "log")` or `family = tw(link = "log")` as reasonable starting points for a model for the response.

If you are using a CH4 flux (and thus might have negative values), then you're now in a world of pain because the data are now heterogeneous but also could take any value on the real number line. Handling that is going to require some care as you need to model the variance as well as the mean. A location scale shape GAM (GAMLSS) might work in that case, as would using `gamm()` with a variance function added via argument `weights` which should be supplied one of the `varFunc` variance functions.

The point however is that you need to build a model that fits the training data without overfitting it. You shouldn't expect the model to recreate the training data perfectly. You should look at the model diagnostics for your model and investigate if it can reproduce features of the data.

Comment: This looks close to my own research. I don't think they are modelling CH4 concentrations. I suspect they are modelling CH4 fluxes between soil and atmosphere. Those can be positive and negative.

Comment: Hello @ Gavin Simpson and @ Roland, to confirm, this model is attempting to model CH4 flux which are positive and negative in my dataset. The dataset of CH4 fluxes were measured in three transect across a number of ponds and wetlands in the study I am using as a reference.

Comment: @ Gavin Simpson, thank you very much for your detailed response and the basic background it provided me on GAMs. Given I have looking at CH4 flux, I'll look more into how to apply GAMLSS and the possibility of using the gamm() with weights.